# Autosys Dependent jobs of ON ICE running immediately after box start

Tags: autosys

Lets say I have a box with 4 jobs. There is some issue with job2, so I want to skip it and go to Job3 after Job1 is completed. Till I fix and test the issue for Job2.

I thought ON ICE job2 will work. But when I do it, as soon as box_a is RU, job1 and job3 are starting same time. But I want job3 to run only after Job1 is SU. What has to be done ?

For now, Im holding the job2 everyday, and next day Im marking it to SU, when job1 is SU and holding again. But for this i have to monitor everyday.

box_a
job1
job2
job3
job4

Answer (score 0):

A would suggest to remove the Job2 from the box assuming its testing is not dependent on the other jobs in the box and update the condition of Job3.

**Save a copy of Job2 and Job3 JIL's.**

Update Job2 JIL:

```
update_job: Job2
box_name:
```

this would remove the job from the box and keep it as in independent job

Next update Job3 JIL:

```
update_job: Job3
condition: success(Job1)
```

Job3 would run after the completion of Job1.

After, the Job2 issue is resolved, update back the Job2 and Job3 JIL with the backup to revert back the temporary changes.

Hope this helps, if any queries do ask.

Answer (score 0):

On Ice is as good as being invisible - so you'll need to update the condition of Job 3 to depend on the success of Job 1 if you have Job 2 on ICE.

Option 2: If you don't want to edit Job 3, make sure you take a back up of Job 2 and replace the command with sleep 1. This acts as a placeholder so you are not changing your entire architecture whilst you debug and plan to put Job 2 back once resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want the job2 to got completion, change the command field to echo, this will ensure that the script is not executed but it will just echo and the job will go to success. Change it back once the issue is fixed.

```
insert_job: test
ob_type: c
command: echo "/home/Autosys/db.sh" 
machine: prod
owner: dev
days_of_week: all
```